# Hilt injecting coroutine dispatcher not working in test

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, dagger-hilt

And then I'm seeing

```
[Test worker @coroutine#1] test
[Test worker @coroutine#2] viewModel
```

So this is giving me problems at the time to verify because it says that there's empty.

I'm using in my viewModel a CoroutineDispatcher injected with Hilt as

```
@HiltViewModel
class LocationsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val locationsUseCase: LocationsUseCase,
    @IODispatcher private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher) : ViewModel() {
 init { viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) { locationsUseCase() }}
}
```

And the test I'm doing

```
private val testDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()

@Test
fun test() = runTest(testDispatcher){ ... }

fun createLocationsViewModel() = LocationsViewModel(locationsUseCase, testDispatcher)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your viewmodel tries to initialise, but fails, because it doesn't know what to do with locationsUseCase call. Try mock it in `setUp()` method. With `mockito-kotlin` and `mockito-core` dependencies it would be something like

```
@Before
fun setUp() = runTest(testDispatcher) {
    whenever(locationsUseCase.invoke()).thenReturn(Result.Success)
}
```

This code is not strict, because I don't know the rest of your code base. So think of it as a reference.